# How to get a SubList from a list based on indices in another List?

Tags: c#, python, linq

#### So, I have 2 lists ,, one contains Objects and another indices of the objects I want from the 1st.

I was wondering if there is a way in **C#** to get a sub-list based on indices stored in another list?

*I'm new to Linq and google didn't answer me yet.*

also what's the **Python**-ic way of doing so?

Of course, i'm already using simple loops to achieve that!

```
List<int> IndexList;
List<int> ObjList;
List<int> subList;


foreach ( var index in IndexList )
    subList.Add(ObjList[index]);
```

Comment: So... do you want Python or C#?

Comment: both :D if possible ,, I'm asking for the pleasure of knowledge, as i already said i'm using the loop way (in a C# code, like the example i provided)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can write a query that includes the index as well as the item, so that you can see if `IndexList` contains the index, and only select those items:

```
List<int> subList = ObjList
    .Where((item, index) => IndexList.Contains(index))
    .ToList();
```

Comment: Thank you, that's exactly what I was looking for ,, can't vote you up though (low reputation)!

Answer (score -1):

```
items = ["a","b","c"]
indexes = [1,2]
mappedList = list(filter(lambda item: items.index(item) in indexes, items))
print(mappedList) # prints: ['b', 'c']
```

To supplement Rufus L's c# answer with a python implementation.